# How to restrict custom field to accept duplicate value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using `register_post_type` to add an input field, let's say "brand_name".
I would like to deny duplicates for that field.

How can I do it in WordPress?
Please help me.

Here is my snippet:

```
function brand_register_meta_boxes() {
if (!class_exists('RW_Meta_Box'))
        return;
    $prefix = 'post_';

    $meta_boxes[] = array(
       'title' => 'Add Brand',
        'pages' => array('brand'),

        'fields' => array(

            array(
            'name' => __( 'Brand Name', 'rwmb' ),
            'desc' => __( 'Add Brand Name', 'rwmb' ),
            'id'   => "{$prefix}title",
            'type' => 'text',
            'required' => true,

            ), 

        )
    );     
        foreach ($meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
        new RW_Meta_Box($meta_box);
    }

}
```

Comment: From what I understand are you adding custom post from an input field. What you can do is save all custom post by adding key/value pair in wordpress DB this function should do the work- add_option( 'brand_name', 'true');   .Then you can check if that custom post type is already registered

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to what you're doing on the `save_post` hook, which is when the custom field is being saved to the database. It looks like you're using the RW Meta Box class. I haven't personally used RW Meta Box, but based on the Github repo over at https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box/blob/master/, you should be able to achieve this by setting `'multiple' => false` for your field defintion.

```
function brand_register_meta_boxes() {
    if (!class_exists('RW_Meta_Box'))
        return;
    $prefix = 'post_';

    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'title' => 'Add Brand',
        'pages' => array('brand'),
        'fields' => array(
            array(
            'name' => __( 'Brand Name', 'rwmb' ),
            'desc' => __( 'Add Brand Name', 'rwmb' ),
            'id'   => "{$prefix}title",
            'type' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'multiple' => false
            ), 
        )
    );     
    foreach ($meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
        new RW_Meta_Box($meta_box);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/function.array-unique

You can use that unique function for unique brand Name